# Hana cloud platform e-mail trigger not sending email

Tags: email, triggers, gmail, sapui5

I am using hana cloud platform and making simple contact form. When user click send button , user's message will send my gmail or outlook account. This my code:

```
    sendEmail: function() {

    var message= this.byId("message").getValue();

    sap.m.URLHelper.triggerEmail( "xxx@gmail.com", "subject", message);
    }
```

When I press send button I am getting this error on console.

```
....was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'mailto:xxx%40gmail.com?subject=subject'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sendEmail: function () {
    var message = this.byId("message").getValue();
    var subject = "Sample Mail";
    var email = encodeURIComponent('xxx@gmail.com');
    window.top.location = 'mailto:'+email+'&subject=' + subject + '&body=' + message);
}
```

`sap.m.URLHelper.triggerEmail` should not have failed in case of HTTPS or whatsoever. Nevertheless the above solution should work in all cases provided default Email client is set.

Comment: thx your comment but ıt still not working. Only navigate to empty page

Comment: copy paste in new tab.. see what happens
mailto:sample@gmail.com